# RXJS: Subscribe adding a new loop on the observable scan operator

Tags: rxjs

I have recently started with RxJS but have not been able to find information with regards to the following:

When scanning an Observable every subscription adds a new iteration to the scanning operation.

It looks like a bug or a bad implementation of the code.

The below link demonstrates this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-bird-0m81p

I have 3 subscriptions, which means 3 extra loops on the scan function.

Comment out a subscription and see the change in the console window.

**Is this expected, is it a bug or is it bad implementation?**

*If it is expected please link to an explanation if possible. Also is it possible to stop this from happening?*

Thanks ahead!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Added a bold text area to clarify

Comment: The answer is: "it's expected". If you really want to share the result of the scan for all subscribers, then use the share() pipe after scan().

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean using share I can limit it to 1 iteration instead of interations = number of subscribers?

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html, http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share

Comment: @JBNizet If you post an answer I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more from the comments from @JB Nizet
How share work is similar to the following code example

```
getShareObservable(){
 const share = new Subject()
 Store$.pipe(
  scan((acc, curr) => {
    console.log("Scanning...");
    return Object.assign({}, acc, curr);
  }, initialState).subscribe(share)
  return share
}

const shareObservable=getShareObservable()
```

then your `scan` won't run multiple times